# Problems opening Bootstrap Modal after using (.reportValidity)

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, event-listener

I am using the what i think is the relatively new .reportValidity function to validate my required fields on a form. This works great, what i would like to achieve is after validation my bootstrap Thank You Modal opens up. I have removed the data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-submit" from my submit button to stop the thank you modal from opening before validation i,m just stuck with the javascript to open it after validation. Here is my code -

For the Validation -

```
    <script>
    document.forms['formfield'].addEventListener('submit', function() {
    document.forms['formfield'].reportValidity();
    }, false);
    </script>
```

For my Bootstrap Modal -

```
    (function(){
    $('##confirm-submit').on('show.bs.modal', function(){
    var myModal = $(this);
    clearTimeout(myModal.data('hideInterval'));
    myModal.data('hideInterval', setTimeout(function(){
        myModal.modal('hide');
    }, 3000));
    });
    });
```

How do i call the Modal after validation and not before?

Comment: the selector for `#confirm-submit` has an extra `#`, which could be breaking some of the code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply K.G i did try and remove one but it didnt make any difference. and it works before validation with the 2 #. I am struggling with calling it after validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was i was over complicating it with a timed Modal, which i didnt need so the final code was -

```
    <script>
    document.forms['formfield'].addEventListener('submit', function() {
    document.forms['formfield'].reportValidity();
    }, false);
    </script>
    <script>
    $('#formfield').on('submit', function(e){
    $('#confirm-submit').modal('show');
    });
    </script>
```

I also added onsubmit="openModal()" into my form name header tag. Now works like a dream.